# How to refer to the parent class from a submodule without naming it

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming

Given this code

```
module A::Internal
  def self.generate_method(name, args)
     A.instance_eval do
        unless self.respond_to? :"#{name}"
           define_method :"#{name}" do
              return true
           end
        end
     end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to refer to `A` in `A.instance_eval do`? I want to place the method `generate_method` on a sublevel (not in the class `A` itself). Is there a way to refer to `A` differently from within `Intenal`?

The method `genrate_method` is on the class level as the genrated method will be on the self level. But for consistency sakes and for a bunch of constant/method, I want to define them in a submodule to avoid collision betwen generated methods for `A` and defined methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
module A
  module Internal
    Module.nesting[1] # => A
  end
end
```

A tricky thing about this is that you have to explicitly nest the modules. If you do

```
module A::Internal
  Module.nesting[1]
end
```

then it will not work.

Comment: thanlk you i'll keep that solution - didn't now that nesting method ;)